# Habilitar o botão "buscar" apenas após o usuário digitar 5 letras - IONIC V3

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic3

tenho um select que me retorna 73mil registros, por isso estou filtrando ele, mas preciso que nesse filtro tenha pelo menos 5 letras ao buscar. Traduzindo: preciso que em tempo real o botão "buscar" só fique disponível quando forem digitadas pelo menos 5 letras, é possível ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, é possível.

Considere que tenha um input como abaixo:

```html
<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Buscar</ion-label>
  <ion-input [(ngModel)]="buscar" (ionChange)="enableButton()" type="text"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<button ion-button color="primary" disable="disableButton" (click)="buscar()">Buscar</button>
```

Então, podemos ter algo assim para controlar o estado do botão de pesquisar.

```js
enableButton() {
  this.disableButton = this.buscar && this.buscar.length < 5;
}
```

Comment: Fiz umas adaptações, mas deu certo!! Valeu cara!

Comment: Que bom que deu certo! Se possível, por favor, avalie a minha resposta. Obrigado!